# I can't install MediaWiki on the google cloud

Tags: apache, mediawiki, gcloud

I installed everything. 
Followed the instructions and then once I finished I put `LocalSettings.php` on the same folder as `index.php`, which is `site/wiki/`.

Yet it still says that `LocalSettings.php` is missing. I typed the address `LocalSettings.php` and it gives me a 404. Its almost as if `LocalSettings.php` is being blocked.

Comment: This is duplicated on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/1012428/i-cant-install-mediawiki-on-the-google-cloud

Answer (score 0):

Also,one of the possible solutions can be deploying [MediaWiki](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/mediawiki) from the Marketplace with one click.